# CellForRow.. Never Being called

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I set up a ViewController (with xib) with a UITableView. I set up the view controller to work as a datasource and delegate for the Table View. Everything seems in place but I cant control the cell data because CellForRow... is never being called.

My .h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>


@property IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;

@end
```

my .m

```
#import "MyViewController.h"

@interface MyViewController ()

@end

@implementation MyViewController

- (id)init{
self = [super init];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
}

- (id) initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {

}
return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

self.tableView.delegate = self;
self.tableView.dataSource = self;

[self.view addSubview:self.tableView];

// Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
// self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

// Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this   view controller.
// self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
}


#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
#warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
// Return the number of sections.
return 0;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
#warning Incomplete method implementation.
// Return the number of rows in the section.
return 0;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

// Configure the cell...

cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
cell.textLabel.text = @"SOMETHING";

return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because you have 0 rows and 0 sections.   Since there are 0 rows and 0 sections... a cell never needs to be created or accessed, so cellForRowAtIndexPath is never sent a message.